# ios - scrollview zooming when scrolling to end, like Fancy

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I don't know what this effect is called. Fancy uses it in its app. It works like this.

- You have an image at the top of a scrollview.
- Drag down and the image gets zoomed to fill the extra top space, so its top edge always remains at the top edge of this scrollview
- release your finger and it bounces back

Please give me some idea on how to build this effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many open source implementations of this, such as:

- https://github.com/apping/APParallaxHeader
- https://github.com/modocache/MDCParallaxView
- https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController

The basic idea behind these is to have an imageview as a subview of the scrollview. When scrolling, you monitor the content offset of the scrollview, and when you reach a certain threshold, you start increasing the image view's height. If you set the image view's `contentMode` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, you will get the effect you want.